# Review Assistance 1.0

Tags: script, review

Review Assistance 1.0 is a script designed to help you review the Close Vote Queue and Reopen Vote Queue in Stack Overflow only.

In future, we will look forward to add it's support to all SE sites.

## How it works?

It appends a link called **status** near the close reason as shown in the image.

[image]

Clicking on it after the post loaded will give you the status of the post.

It can show 6 different statuses.

## If the question didn't have an existing Close Vote and is open

It will alert

[image]

## If the question have existing Close Votes and is open

It will alert

[image]

## Reopen Queue

## If it is an audit

It will alert

[image]

## If it don't have existing reopen votes

It will alert

[image]

## If it has existing reopen votes

It will alert

[image]

[Click to Install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sagarvd01/SO/master/Src/Scripts/Review%20Assistance%201.0.js)

License : MIT License

Github Repo : [Repo](https://github.com/sagarvd01/SO/tree/master/Src/Scripts)

Version : 1.0

> Note : The script file is minified, in order to reduce the size by 50%.